# why does Ruby Thread act up in this example - effectively missing files

Tags: ruby, xml, multithreading, nokogiri

I have a 50+ GB XML file which I initially tried to (man)handle with Nokogiri :)

Got `killed: 9` - obviously :)

Now I'm into muddy Ruby threaded waters with this stab (at it):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def add_vehicle index, str
  IO.write "ess_#{index}.xml", str
  #file_name = "ess_#{index}.xml"
  #fd = File.new file_name, "w"
  #fd.write str
  #fd.close
  #puts file_name
end

begin

  record = []
  threads = []
  counter = 1
  file = File.new("../ess2.xml", "r")
  while (line = file.gets)
    case line
    when /<ns:Statistik/                           
      record = []
      record << line
    when /<\/ns:Statistik/                         
      record << line
      puts "file - %s" % counter
      threads << Thread.new { add_vehicle counter, record.join }
      counter += 1
    else
      record << line
    end
  end
  file.close
  threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
rescue => err
    puts "Exception: #{err}"
    err
end
```

Somehow this code 'skips' one or two files when writing the result files - hmmm!?

Comment: Just curious. What is this file? I looked for the node, and found a danish list of motor parts. Or something.

Comment: Trying to slurp a big file will kill any language. Instead, when parsing XML you need to use a [SAX parser, which Nokogiri does implement](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/SAX). I'd suggest reading up on how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you have a problem because your file is huge, and you want to use multithreading.

Now have you. problemstwo

On a more serious note, I've had very good experience with this [code](https://gist.github.com/kmile/827475).

It parsed 20GB xml files with almost no memory use.

Download the mentioned code, save it as `xml_parser.rb` and this script should work :

```
require_relative 'xml_parser.rb'

file = "../ess2.xml"

def add_vehicle index, str
  filename = "ess_#{index}.xml"
  File.open(filename,'w+'){|out| out.puts str}
  puts format("%s has been written with %d lines", filename, str.each_line.count)
end

i=0
Xml::Parser.new(Nokogiri::XML::Reader(open(file))) do
  for_element 'ns:Statistik' do
    i+=1
    add_vehicle(i,@node.outer_xml)
  end
end

#=> ess_1.xml has been written with 102 lines
#=> ess_2.xml has been written with 102 lines
#=> ...
```

It will take time, but it should work without error and without using much memory.

By the way, here is the reason why your code missed some files :

```
threads = []
counter = 1
threads << Thread.new { puts counter }
counter += 1
threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
#=> 2

threads = []
counter = 1
threads << Thread.new { puts counter }
sleep(1)
counter += 1
threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
#=> 1
```

`counter += 1` was faster than the `add_vehicle` call. So your `add_vehicle` was often called with the wrong counter. With many millions node, some might get 0 offset, some might get 1 offset. When 2 `add_vehicle` are called with the same id, they overwrite each other, and a file is missing.

You have the same problem with `record`, with lines getting written in the wrong file.

Comment: hi @eric-duminil - so good of you to chime in :)

do you mean to say that the counter += 1 'messes' with the counter variable before Thread.new is setup and calls add_vehicle?

Comment: @walt_die : exactly. It's called a race condition : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition and well, it sucks.

Comment: your code had me moving on - which is great :) I've seen race conditions _en masse_ in my career; I never actually planned to be the culprit myself :) Here's to _by reference_

perhaps your DSL could marry https://github.com/ohler55/ox and have a phenomenally fast and monumentally elegant _baby_ :D

Answer (score 1):

Perhabs you should try to synchronize `counter += 1` with Mutex.
For example: 

`@lock = Mutex.new
@counter = 0
def add_vehicle str
     @lock.synchronize do
        @counter += 1
        IO.write "ess_#{@counter}.xml", str
     end 
end`

Mutex implements a simple semaphore that can be used to coordinate access to shared data from multiple concurrent threads.

Or you can go another way from the start and use [Ox](https://github.com/ohler55/ox). It is way faster than Nokogiri, take a look on a [comparison](http://www.ohler.com/dev/xml_with_ruby/xml_with_ruby.html). For a huge files [Ox::Sax](http://www.ohler.com/ox/Ox/Sax.html)

Comment: thx so much for your suggestions - and the Ox parser does indeed look promising!